# How do i make my program read in value=judges

Tags: c

Program will read in number of Judges=x. Then it will read marks scored by number of judges=x.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int judges,counter;
bool sum, marks, highmark, lowmark;
int main (){
printf("Enter number of judges");
scanf("%d", &judges);
while (judges<3 || judges>10){
printf("Invalid number of Judges\nPlease enter number between 3 to 10");
scanf("%d", &judges);
}
printf("Enter Marks");
scanf("%f", &marks);
while (marks<1.0 || marks>12.0){
printf("Wrong Mark, please Enter a Mark between 1.0 to 12.0");
scanf("%f", &marks);
}
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and you haven't asked a question.

Comment: You should [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your code before doing enything else. Oh and `print f`-> `printf` and `scan f` -> `scanf`. And `high mark` -> `high_mark` and And `low mark` -> `low_mark`.

Comment: It would appear that the format %d expects an int* but you gave it a bool*. How much clearer can a compiler error get?

Comment: `bool`? Are you using a C++ compiler instead of a C one? The C type is `_Bool` and you're not including `<stdbool.h>` to get the `bool` alias...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what your question is.
As Lundin already stated in his comment you are using the wrong format specifier.

```
scan f("%d", &marks);
```

Your marks is a bool and you define a format specifier for integer variables (%d).

Later in your code you seem to use marks as a floating point variable, so you may consider the following snippet.

```
float marks;
scanf("%f", &marks);
```

Please clearify and edit your topic and provide a clear question.

I hope this suggestion can help you.

For further format specifier of the scanf method you can visit [scanf format specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: The program will read the number of judges=x, then it should ask to read x times marks for the x judges entered. I dont know where to put the loop. A for loop or while loop?